# IOS Parse implementation Error

Tags: ios, runtime-error, implementation, parse-platform

I am trying to implement Parse and when I add it to the framework through the build phrase into my linked libraries, I get errors. I get

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Parse", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

When I try to implement

[Parse setApplicationId:@"XXXXXXXXX" clientKey:@"XXXXXXXX"];

In my app delegate.

I am using JTRevealSideBarDemoV2 and I am not 100% familiar with how targets work.  There are multiple targets available however I usually set the target to the the one that I am using.

http://i44.tinypic.com/2v9q1rq.png

I have done a lot of research on this issue and I think it has something to do with my targets so if you could explain what you think may be wrong, it would be awesome!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you go through Parse's iOS QuickStart guide? It lists all the required frameworks.

Comment: I am an idiot, I got so consumed on wondering why it wasn't working that I forgot that their was more too implementing Parse than just adding it to your framework. Rookie mistake! Thanks.